# jQuery callback not waiting on fadeOut

Tags: jquery, callback, fadein, fadeout

It seems to me the following code should produce these results:

```
mademoiselle
demoiselle
mesdemoiselles
```

Instead, as "ma" fades out, "mes" fades in making the sequence:

```
mademoiselle
madesdemoiselles
mesdemoiselles
```

The code:

```
<span class="remove">ma</span><span class="add">mes</span>demoiselle<span class="add">s</span>

$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".remove").fadeOut(4000,function(){
       $(".add").fadeIn(5000);      
   });
});
```

Edit: I found an empty span that if I remove makes the bug go away:

```
<span class="remove">ma</span><span class="add">mes</span>demoiselle<span class="remove"></span><span class="add">s</span>
```

The problem is: The php code generating this is using the spans as placeholders. I'll str_replace them if I have to, but I'm curious why this is happening.

Comment: Sample produces expected behavior for me on Safari 4.0.3 and FF 3.5. What browsers did you test?

Comment: What browser are you using, I've tried this in Firefox, and it works as you would expect.

Comment: I've tried it on FF3.05 and Safari 4.03

It must be something else on the page. Do I need to have the jQuery in the head?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, so I managed to reproduce your problem see the example at http://jsbin.com/ocaha.

What's happening is that jQuery can see that your empty `<span>` does not need to be faded out. Therefor it considers the animation done and executes for 0ms instead of the expected 4000ms. So it immediately starts fading in **all** of the `.adds`.

To prevent this behaviour, I would [filter](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/filter#expr) away all empty elements from the selection. Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".remove")
               .filter(function(){ return ! $(this).is(":empty"); })
               .fadeOut(4000, function(){
     $(".add").fadeIn(5000);
   });
});
```

See working example at http://jsbin.com/ovivi.

Answer (score 3):

Change ":***empty***" to ":***hidden***" if not working:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".remove")
               .filter(function(){ return ! $(this).is(":hidden"); })
               .fadeOut(4000, function(){
     $(".add").fadeIn(5000);
   });
});
```