# jQuery fade out fade in replaces text while jumping instead of overlaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The below code is running on the following web page. If you click any of the three buttons on the left under the rotating banner you will see the behaviour I talk about. The text next to the buttons is meant to fade out and fade in a new section. But the new section fades in before the first is gone and jumps back up.

I thought as I was using a callback function for the fade in that this would not occur. Can anyone advise as to what I should be doing?

http://www.tacticalsalestraining.co.uk/

```
<span style="float:left;">
  <a target="_blank" href="http://www.tacticalsalestraining.co.uk/sales-training-courses-listing" class="textbutton" data-conn="text1">
  <img src="/images/OpenOver.png" alt="Open Courses" width="300" height="47">
  </a><br />
    <a target="_blank" href="http://www.tacticalsalestraining.co.uk/sales-training-courses-listing" class="textbutton"  data-conn="text2">
  <img src="/images/InHouseOver.png" alt="In House Training" width="300" height="47">
  </a><br />
  &nbsp;
    <a href="http://tacticalsalestraining.com/seminars/seminars_full.html" class="textbutton"  data-conn="text3">
  <img src="/images/FreetoAttendOver.png" alt="Free to Attend" width="300" height="47">
  </a>
</span>
<span style="width:610px;height:200px;float:right; background-color:#bcbcbc;font-size:15px;line-height:15px;">
<div class="texts" id="text"><h1>UK's Fastest Growing Sales Training Company</h1>
Tactical Sales Training, providers of measurably effective sales courses for all industries. We offer training that's interactive, effective and straight out of our own playbook.<br />
We practice what we teach; the courses are filled with exactly what we do back in the office when prospecting for new clients or looking to close deals. 

</div>
<span class="texts" id="text1" style="display:none;"><h2>Action Based Open Sales Courses, Nationwide</h2>
Trouble getting new business? Difficulty closing that deal? How's your qualification going? These are questions that can define the difference between a good or great sales person. We've helped 100s of businesses exponentially increase their sales with our open courses, what can we do for you?
</span>
<span class="texts" id="text2" style="display:none;"><h2>For the More Tricky Sales Processes</h2>
Getting to the root of the problem or finding the perfect solution can be a call for our bespoke option. Many national and international companies have opted for this because they wanted us to look deep into their sales processes.<br /><br />
They also wanted the perfect solution with instantly actionable solutions that prove the effectiveness with measurable results. We've provided just that, every single time we go out on a bespoke mission.
</span>
<span class="texts" id="text3" style="display:none;">Content Text</span>
</span>
<script>
$(".textbutton").click(function(){
var link = $(this).attr("data-conn");
        $(".texts").fadeOut(1000, function() {
            $("#"+link).fadeIn(1000);
        });
        return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: this qusestion perhaps help you:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678013/jquery-callback-not-waiting-on-fadeout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem with your script is that you apply **fadeOut** on all items with ***texts*** class & try to **fadeIn** one of them back. The better approach would be to keep track of the current selected text, say by adding another class ***selected***.

Here is the modified script you could work on. One of the items with ***texts*** class has to have the ***selected*** class all the time.

```
$(".textbutton").click(function(){
   var link = $(this).attr("data-conn"); 
   $(".texts.selected").removeClass("selected").fadeOut(1000, function() { 
          $("#"+link).addClass("selected").fadeIn(1000); 
          });
   return false;
});

$(".texts:first()").addClass("selected");
```